# the file doesnt exist but still im getting error for that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a react-native app,
I use expo so I can run it, but when it runs, it gives me this error everytime,

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\KobitPC\Desktop\react\online\ppm20- 
onlineshop\assets\favicon.png'
```

I don't have a file named like this, and I don't import it anywhere on my components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` folder, then run `npm install`.
If the above mentioned didn't work. Try the following:

```
npm cache clean --force && npm i -g npm && npm i
```